# Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: “org.eclipse.jface” eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

the following error occured when I started modelling from my TAOM4E Agent Modelling plug-in:

Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface"

The full errorlog is as follows:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2017-06-22 01:06:39.783
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at it.itc.sra.taom4e.platform.model.ModelCreationFactory.getNewObject(ModelCreationFactory.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.gef.requests.CreateRequest.getNewObject(CreateRequest.java:77)
    at it.itc.sra.taom4e.platform.edit.policies.mixeddiagram.MixedDiagramContainerXYLayoutEditPolicy.getCreateCommand(MixedDiagramContainerXYLayoutEditPolicy.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editpolicies.LayoutEditPolicy.getCommand(LayoutEditPolicy.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editpolicies.ConstrainedLayoutEditPolicy.getCommand(ConstrainedLayoutEditPolicy.java:175)
    at it.itc.sra.taom4e.platform.edit.policies.mixeddiagram.MixedDiagramContainerXYLayoutEditPolicy.getCommand(MixedDiagramContainerXYLayoutEditPolicy.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.getCommand(AbstractEditPart.java:501)
    at it.itc.sra.taom4e.platform.edit.parts.DiagramObjectEditPart.getCommand(DiagramObjectEditPart.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.gef.dnd.AbstractTransferDropTargetListener.getCommand(AbstractTransferDropTargetListener.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.gef.dnd.AbstractTransferDropTargetListener.handleDrop(AbstractTransferDropTargetListener.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.gef.dnd.TemplateTransferDropTargetListener.handleDrop(TemplateTransferDropTargetListener.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.gef.dnd.AbstractTransferDropTargetListener.drop(AbstractTransferDropTargetListener.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.DelegatingDropAdapter$3.run(DelegatingDropAdapter.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.DelegatingDropAdapter.drop(DelegatingDropAdapter.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DNDListener.handleEvent(DNDListener.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget.Drop(DropTarget.java:456)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget.Drop_64(DropTarget.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget$3.method6(DropTarget.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COMObject.callback6(COMObject.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COM.DoDragDrop(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSource.drag(DragSource.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSource.access$0(DragSource.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSource$1.handleEvent(DragSource.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.log.EventDetailsDialog.open(EventDetailsDialog.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.log.EventDetailsDialogAction.run(EventDetailsDialogAction.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.log.LogView$15.doubleClick(LogView.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:824)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:822)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleDoubleSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1421)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1225)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$0(OpenStrategy.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)
```

I tried everything. I hope there is anybody to help!

kind regards

Sma

Comment: What code does this have an error on?

Comment: No Code, this happens when I add a Symbol from the TAOM4E work perspective on a Diagramm. I can't add Symbols. immediately the error occurs. It is a Graphic Tool to creat goal diagramms!

Comment: The error is in `it.itc.sra.taom4e.platform.model.ModelCreationFactory` - is this your code?

Comment: No, I think it is the code from the installed plugin.

Comment: i can#t use plugin and dont know why. any help?